# How to create "Invite Friends" button in android?

Tags: android

[I want open this type of window when I click "Invite Friends" button & after selecting any of them I wand paste the link for my app in the selected application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT2tm.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try below code to share your link:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR_LINK");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see complete example "[How to Create Refer a friend Link](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/referral-program-using-firebase-dynamic-link-android-tutorial/)"

You need to add Firebase Dynamic link(Firebase Invites depreciated now). Firebase Dymanic Link is build over Firebase Invites So you can see the invites dependency on gradle file.

**There is Two ways to create "Refer a Friend Link"**

1. Using Firebase base Dynamic Object
2. Manually Create Refer a Link

1) Option :-

```
DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
        .setLink(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/"))
        //.setDomainUriPrefix("https://example.page.link")  // no longer in user please
        .setDynamicLinkDomain("example.page.link")  // use this code and don't use https:// here
        // Open links with this app on Android
        .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
        // Open links with com.example.ios on iOS
        .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.example.ios").build())
        .buildDynamicLink();
Uri dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
```

2) Option:-

```
String sharelinktext  = "https://referearnpro.page.link/?"+
              "link=https://www.blueappsoftware.com/"+
              "&apn="+ getPackageName()+
              "&st="+"My Refer Link"+
              "&sd="+"Reward Coins 20"+
              "&si="+"https://www.blueappsoftware.com/logo-1.png";
```

Then Call **ShortDynamicLink** Object

Refer Link will be look like this :

```
https://referearnpro.page.link?apn=blueappsoftware.referearnpro&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blueappsoftware.com%2F
```

You can check complete [example here](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/referral-program-using-firebase-dynamic-link-android-tutorial/)